# How to open a windows form app, from another windows forms app

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

Hi im kinda new to programing and im stuck on a simple problem. 
I have two windows forms projects: WindowsFormsApp1 and WindowsFormsApp2, and i need to open the second one from a button in one,keeping in mind that they both have multiple forms, i need to pass variables from one to the other, and when i close 2, i need to open 1 again. 
But i really have no idea on how to do so, and i can't seem to find anything online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start other application by using `Process.Start("OtherApplication.exe")`.
Once your second application is compiled, enter the path of the .exe and you are all set.

Here's the documentation for Process.Start(): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#overloads

Comment: Thanks i was tying to avoid using process.start to see if there was a way to launch the project from the same solution, but i had a problem with circular references, so i think this is going to be the easier method.

Answer (score 0):

Reference the secondary application project from your main project.
The button in your main project can then close or hide your main project's window(s) and call a method from your second project. You may want to provide a specific method for that purpose, to make it easier to pass variables.
When that method returns, reopen (or unhide) the main UI.

Note: if this needs to go both ways, this won't work - you can't have circular references. In such a case, you might have to start the applications' binaries, probably using `Process.Start`. The drawback is that you then need to arrange the passing of data between them via command line arguments.

Comment: You can't have circular references, but you can do this with a third project that defines an interface that one (or both) of the forms implements.

Answer (score 0):

1. Why not make them under one solution? You can do that by right clicking on your solution in the "Solution Explorer" then "Add" and "New Project" or you can try with "Existing Project" you must select the ".csproj" file in the directory of your second project. After adding it it should appear in your "Solution Explorer" with all the files like a different project. After that you can find "References" under your project in the "Solution Explorer". Right click on it and select "Add Reference" then under "Project" you will find your second project and then "Add" it. Then by typing 
   "using SecondProjectName;" you will reference it and then you can use classes from your second project! Hopefully this helped! But if your form class is "internal" you will not be able to use code from it, because "internal" makes it so the code can be used only in the specific project.
2. Another way is to use "Process.Start(@"SecondProjectExeFilePath");". The @ sign means that the string has escaping characters like /,\ etc. You can read more at "docs.micosoft.com" :)